# Flutter: How to add a progress dialog when tap on a button?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a progress dialog when tapping on my button.

Below is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(child: Text('Login')),
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2e80e4)
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/logo.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Username',
                  hintText: 'Please enter your username'
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 0),
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  hintText: 'Please enter your password'
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                  await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forget_password');
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Forget Password',
                  style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff2e80e4), fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
                width: 250.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: const Color(0xff2e80e4),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                 //here I need to start the progress dialog
                  http.Response response = await postRequest();
                  Map<String, dynamic> parsedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
                  LoginResponse loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(parsedData);
                  if(loginResponse.verificationStatus)
                  {
                    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                  }
                  //Here I need to stop the progress dialog
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 100.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign_up');
              },
                child: Text(
                    'New User? Create Account',
                  style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff2e80e4), fontSize: 15.0),
                ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I like to start the progress dialog when I tap on the login button and stop it after loading home page. Is it possible to use `flutter_spinkit` for this? I tried, but no progres, I am very new to flutter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question in the answer above (Don't have reputation to comment):
You can use Stack Widget to stack children widgets on top of one another. Return Sizebox.shrink() for an empty widget.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(
      title: Center(child: Text('Login')),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2e80e4)
  ),
  body: Stack(children: [
      _isLoading ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : SizedBox.shrink(),
      YourSingleChildScrollView
      ])
  }
```

Comment: I tried this and working fine as expected, but the background layout is enable when progress dialogs appear. So I can tap on username or password fields again. How we can disable the  entire background layout when the progress dialog starts?

Comment: TextField widget has a property called enabled which if false the TextField will be disabled and cannot be edited. set the enabled property to be ! _isLoading so whenever is _isLoading is true the TextFields will be disabled. You should read up on the documentation of the Widgets if you need them to do something.
Source: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html

Comment: Is it possible to disable the entire UI when the login button tapped? Because I have button, textfield and some other texts on the UI. Disabling all is easy instead of disabling one by one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I fixed that, check my below answer

Answer (score 1):

You can manage it using state as updating state rerender your widget and show content according to your condition . Kindly find below updated code and let us know if something is missed over here

**Note :- I am assuming over here that your widget is extending `StatefulWidget` not `StatelessWidget` as you added `build` method only**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(child: Text('Login')),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xff2e80e4)
      ),
      body: _isLoading ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),) : SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  height: 150,
                  child: Image.asset('assets/logo.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Username',
                    hintText: 'Please enter your username'
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15.0, bottom: 0),
              child: TextField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Password',
                    hintText: 'Please enter your password'
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forget_password');
              },
              child: Text(
                'Forget Password',
                style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff2e80e4), fontSize: 15.0),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50.0,
              width: 250.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: const Color(0xff2e80e4),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
              ),
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async{
                  setState(() {
                    _isLoading = true;
                  });
                  //here I need to start the progress dialog
                  http.Response response = await postRequest();
                  Map<String, dynamic> parsedData = jsonDecode(response.body);
                  LoginResponse loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(parsedData);
                  if(loginResponse.verificationStatus)
                  {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLoading = false;
                    });
                    await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home');
                  }
                  //Here I need to stop the progress dialog
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),

            SizedBox(height: 100.0),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () async{
                await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/sign_up');
              },
              child: Text(
                'New User? Create Account',
                style: TextStyle(color: const Color(0xff2e80e4), fontSize: 15.0),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you mentioned that you are beginner , I would like to suggest to go through State management in flutter as it will help you to do many things

https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/interactive

Comment: My widget is extending a StatefulWidget. I tried this and progress dialog is showing on the UI. But when progress dialog appears, my login UI is hiding, I need the login UI on the background. Any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to disable the entire UI when the login button tapped? Because I have button, textfield and some other texts on the UI. Disabling all is easy instead of disabling one by one.

I fix this issue like below:

Created below loading indicator

```
buildLoading(BuildContext context) {
return showDialog(
  context: context,
  barrierDismissible: false,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
      ),
    );
  });
}
```

Then call it anywhere using:

```
buildLoading(context);
```

and dismiss it when loading is done using:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```